# Raising to the power of $i$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

We all know the usual exponentiation $a^i$ in the complex setting; one can ask is there such a map in a given group; more specifically is there a criterion in the general sense such that given an abelian group $G$ one can determine with the criterion whether there is a homomorphism $\phi_{i}$ such that for any $x \in G$ we have that $\phi_{i}(\phi_i(x)) = x^{-1}$  (because we need $(x^{i})^{i} = x^{-1}$ this is ofcourse very informal).

Note that for groups $Z/(p)$ there is such a criterion. If there is a map $\phi_{i} $ in $Z/(p)$ then given a primitive element $q \in Z/(p)$ one has that $\phi_i(q) = q^{a}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ hence $\phi_i(q^{a}) \equiv q^{a^2} \equiv q^{-1}$ hence $a^2+1 \equiv 0$ $mod$ $(p-1)$ which is iff there is no prime $r$ that is $3 $ mod $4$ dividing $p-1$.

One automatically realizes that $Z/(2)$ has such a homomorphism, for $p \geq 3$ we also need

$p \equiv 3$ mod$(4)$ as for $p \equiv 1$ mod $(4)$ we have that $p-1 \equiv 0 mod 4$ and hence if $\phi_i(q^{a}) \equiv q^{a^2} \equiv q^{-1}$ mod $(p)$ we have that $a^2+1 \equiv 0 mod 4$ which is impossible.

After working through the details one arrives at the conclusion that if there is a homomorphism $\phi_{i}$ in $Z/(p)$ then $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 3 $ mod $(4)$ and $p-1$ has no prime $q$ which is $3$ mod $(4)$   (we need that any prime $q$ which is $3$ mod $(4)$ does not divide $p-1$).

This criterion is only for a small class of finite groups.

Comment: I’m having trouble following the string of statements in the last paragraph which has your question embedded in there somewhere

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You write "We all know the usual exponentiation $a^i$ in the complex setting." Actually, there are many questions posted at MSE from users who are uncertain about or confused by the rules of complex exponentiation.

Comment: Well there are different interpretations of "we all".

Comment: Note that if $\phi_i$ is an automorphism, then $\phi_i^2$ is the inverting automorphism as you’ve pointed out. This implies that $G$ must be abelian, as this is no longer an automorphism for nonabelian groups.

Comment: We all know that the automorphism group of $\mathbf{Z}/p$ is the cyclic group $(\mathbf{Z}/p)^*$ which has an element of order $4$ (whose square is necessarily $-1$) if and only if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So we all know that the answer in the case of groups of prime order is when $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So maybe you might want to "work through the details" again since all of your claims are wrong.

Comment: As noted previously, the group $G$ has to be abelian. If $G$ is finite, then it is a product of its $p$-Sylows so you may as well assume it is a finite abelian $p$-group. If $G = \mathbf{Z}/p^n$ then one wants $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ or $p^n = 2$. For non-cyclic groups, note that  $(\mathbf{Z}/p^n)^2$ always has an order $4$ automorphism with square $-1$ for any $p$ given by

$$\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: In fact, this is enough to determine out the answer completely when $G$ is finite. Namely, $G$ is a direct sum of the examples above. That is, there is no restriction on the $p$-Sylow for $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, but the factors of $(\mathbf{Z}/p^n)$ for $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ or $p^n \ge 4$  with $p = 2$ have to occur with even multiplicity. To see this, use induction to reduce to the case $(\mathbf{Z}/p^n)^k$ and note that the eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix must all be $i$ or $-i$. If $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, then $i \notin \mathbf{F}_p$ so $i$ and $-i$ must occur as a conjugate pair.

Comment: There is no such homomorphism when  $p = 1 mod$  4 I.e you can test $p = 5$

Comment: If $G$ has order $5$ then $\phi(x) = x^2$ is an automorphism of order $4$ with $\phi(\phi(x))  = (x^2)^2 = x^4 = x^{-1}$.

Comment: $x^4 = identity$

Comment: No, $x^4$ is not the identity in a group of order $5$. That contradicts Lagrange's theorem, for a start. The only thing I can possibly imagine is happening is that you don't know the difference between a "group" and a "field" and your question is really about a finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$ with $p$ elements, where a field is a structure that has both addition and subtraction. And, for the particular case of $\mathbf{F}_p$, one has $x^p = x$ for every element $x \in \mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: x^4 -= identity in $Z/5 $

Comment: i.e $2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 1 $ mod $5$

Comment: I think you are confused by the group I am talking about $Z/{p}$ has $p-1$ elements

Comment: Nobody in their right mind uses $Z/p$ to refer to a group with $p-1$ elements. $\mathbf{Z}/p$ is the additive group of order $p$. If you want to talk about the multiplicative group of non-zero elements, that is denoted $(\mathbf{Z}/p)^{\times}$. Anyway, my comments give the general solution for all finite (abelian) groups, using the standard notation.

Comment: yep that is my bad your answer is correct thanks

Comment: @BarryCipra: I'd guess that the OP and the one upvoting his/her answer to your comment are unaware of complex analysis and the concept of Riemannian surfaces with their implications to writing complex numbers in the exponent.